# How to allocate a struct to shared memory i c++?

Tags: c++, struct, shared-memory

I have a vague idea of how to work with shared memory in C and I'm trying to use the same approach in a C++ program.
I want to share a struct:

```
typedef struct 
{
    string passw;
    string encoded;
    string tries;
    char steps;
}gameInfo;

gameInfo *gI;
```

And this is how I'm trying to do it:

```
int memory;
memory = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(gameInfo)*max_players, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
if(memory==-1)
    {printf("Shared memory error");}
```

(Later)

```
*gI = shmat(memory,NULL,0);
```

And I get "error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘gameInfo’ and ‘void*’)" errors.
What would be the quickest fix?

Comment: Lookup _placement `new()`_.

Comment: Note that you also have to make sure `std::string` uses shared memory to store the string contents, when it does allocations... IOW, you should probably just use plain C char arrays for this purpose. Fixed length, wrapped inside the struct as struct members.

Comment: Your approach is flawed anyway: std::strings use the heap by default and thus can't live in shared memory.

Comment: `gI = (gameInfo*)shmat(memory,NULL,0);` (but as others have said, you can't use `std::string` with shared memory)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you managed to understand how to use placement [`new`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new), you would not be able to get your example running on Linux using POSIX shared memory from [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html).

Because [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is not a POD class and contains *internal* pointers whose role and behavior is not specified.

Comment: But an allocator can be specified for everything in the standard lib.

Comment: But then it is no more the usual `std::string`